# Cross-Domain Request Header Value in MVC WEB API C#

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

How to Read header value sent from cross domain application
I have followed the following [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) to enable cross-domain calls On `API`
but when from jquery I'm setting a Custom header on server side it show something like.

```
"Access-Control-Request-Header": "tauth-header"
```

But I'm not able get value of my custom header tauth-header

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because of security reasons,browser do not allow access to cross-domain-header or cross-domain cookies from other domain. Access is restricted to same domain.

Comment: Thank for your answer but i'm trying to read it on Server Side

Comment: Have you set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' correctly? Does it have entry for "tauth-header" header?

Comment: I implemented through WebApiConfig like following code snippet public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
        // ...
    }
}"

Comment: Try using following attributes [EnableCors(origins: "*", 
    headers: "Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With,tauth-header", methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS")]

Comment: Also, check browser developer window (In case of Chrome > press F12 > this opens the developers window) while sending the request for CORS call to server, does it gives any error messages while sending the custom header "tauth-header".

Comment: Have you checked the browsers developer window? Does it showing any error in console?

Comment: No Its not showing any error, calls are successfully executed and